# url routing and rewriting in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing some issues in url routing.

Actually I have done url rewriting and url routing in my web application and every think is working fine but a problem which i am facing is that

```
  public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {        
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

        static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapPageRoute("admin", "admin", "~/adminpanel.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("companyPanel", "company", "~/companyPanel.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("default", "default", "~/default.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("CustomerDetails", "Details/{*propertyid}", "~/AdDetails.aspx",false);
            routes.MapPageRoute("NewRecord", "NewRecord", "~/AdProperty.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("PropertyRecords", "PropertyRecords", "~/agentsAds.aspx");

        }


        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
`
```

in above syntax when I open company page its working fine and url is looking like this "localhost:10852/company" and when i go to detail page i am also passing value in url like this "localhost:10852/Details/33"
and when again i go to company page than url looks like this "localhost:10852/Details/company" but it should be like this"localhost:10852/company"...
it removed only propertyid from url but previous page is still present in url kindly tell me how can i remove previous page "details" name. kindly help me

Comment: kindly help me if any body knows the solution....

Comment: Are you navigating from company to detail and vice versa using an anchor tag if so kindly share the HTML. Just showing **RegisterRoutes** method isn't enough to know your actual problem.

Comment: <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("propertyID", "~/Details/{0}") %>' Text="View Details"></asp:HyperLink> this page is to pass value to detailed page and when again i want to move on another page than the problem occure....it romoves only parameter from url and dnt remove the pagename of previous page

Comment: actually sir "details/{proeprtyid}" in this syntax property id is value which i m passing to another page in url but when i go to detail page and than tried to ga back to any other page than only "propertyid" is reomove and "details" is not removed from url and i want to remove both "details/{proeprtyid}" for example i want to go back to company page than url will be looked like this "localhost/10852/detail/company" but it should be like this "localhost/10852/company" . thanks